# Why does this getter inside a function produce a syntax error?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

In Dart Editor build 27025, the following code produces a syntax error on the line declaring the getter `get x`:

```
main() {
  var _x;
  set x(x) => _x = x; // This is okay
  get x => _x;        // Syntax error here
}
```

Note that the setter `set x` doesn't produce an error. Is this a bug in Dart Editor or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Dart defines getters and setters as functions, so they should be declarable inside other functions. Here's the related language spec: **Functions include function declarations, methods, getters, setters and function literals. ... Getters are functions that are used to retrieve the values of object properties. ... Setters are functions that are used to set the values of object properties.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, *getters are functions that are used to retrieve the values of object properties* and *setters are functions that are used to set the values of object properties*.  In you example code, `_x` is not an object property.

The [spec](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.ed5f44k6gfp) shows that *getterSignature* and *setterSignature* are only allowed in classes and at the top-level of libraries.

The only thing that surprises me is that your `set` doesn't produce a syntax error.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you use getters and setters in other isolates? When using `spawnFunction()` to create an `Isolate`, all that isolate's code goes inside one function, correct? So you can't use getters or setters there?

Comment: @Ganymede I haven't had a chance to play with isolates yet, but my understanding is that `spawnFunction()` takes any top-level function as its argument and spawns a new isolate that begins execution with that function.  That function can call other functions, refer to classes, use getters and setters on objects, etc.  There's no reason to try to cram everything the function uses into the function body.

Comment: You can put getters and setters into top-level of libraries, FWIW.

Comment: Outside static context the token 'set' is treated like a normal variable. In your case the parser treats it like the return type (and, for example, `Set` is actually a very common return type). The editor (or any other analyzer) should complain that the type `set` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting one. I think the bug may be that it doesn't complain about the setter. If you delete the getter and just use the setter it doesn't actually run. Or even parse. Which I think means they're not allowed within a function, though it's not immediately clear to me why.

Answer (score 0):

A Dart project member responded to my bug report that "it isn't valid to declare a getter or a setter inside another method or function. This can be seen by following the grammar for a statement to a localFunctionDeclaration to a functionSignature.

That said, it's a bug that there was no syntax error for the setter."